# Responsive Previous and Next Navigation

Tags: html, css

Trying to make navigation with Previous and Next button.

Want the Previous and Next to be on both ends of the screen. They need to be responsive and float closer to each other with the size of the screen. However, the previous and next buttons can't be one over the other.

My current CSS and HTML is as follows:

HTML

```
<div id="navigation_wrapper">
<div><a href="previous.html">previous</a><a href="next.html">next</a></div></div>
```

Connected CSS

```
div#navigation_wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 5px 0px 30px 0px;
   background-color: orange; 
   opacity:0.8;
 }
```

Comment: If I understand your problem right, then you need to set a min-width of at minimum the size of both links. Then they stay next to each other, whatever happens.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zpYuY/

Comment: editted the jsfiddle of Mr. Alien : http://jsfiddle.net/zpYuY/1/ simply setting a min-width of 0 stops the items from going over eachother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should float the elements like so

CSS

```
div#navigation_wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: orange; 
   opacity:0.8;
 }
#prev-button {
    float:left;
}
#next-button {
    float:right;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="navigation_wrapper">
    <a id="prev-button" href="previous.html">previous</a>
    <a id="next-button" href="next.html">next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float the buttons left / right accordingly and to avoid them colliding set `min-width` on the body tag

[quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/Q3PpE/)

```
body{
    min-width:120px
}
div#navigation_wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 5px 0px;
   background-color: orange; 
   opacity:0.8;
    overflow:hidden;
 }
a[href*="previous.html"]{
    float: left;
}

a[href*="next.html"]{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: im sorry but this solution does not work for if the width gets smaller then 120px it pushes the code outside the screen. Watch http://jsfiddle.net/zpYuY/1/ for a fix for that.

Comment: the slider div in your example does nothing. remove it and the corresponding styles and it still behaves the same. which devices are you targeting that have a resolution lower than 120px?

Comment: it was all for examples, i cant imagine anyone having 2 arrows on their site without actually having a purpose so i assumed it was for a slider. But the div name and the width can both be easily adjusted. It was simply to show that it worked and if they are in a div it can be styled much easier as well.